# Mail Tracking for Users Location (Track Users Location while reading mail)

Tags: php, email, geolocation

I want to track user's location when user read mail. I have added 1x1px image for tracking in which it will call my location script and store user location in database.

Location script is (locations.php)

```
$location_details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."/json"));    
$locationtext =  "Location : ".$location_details->city." ".$location_details->region." ".$location_details->country;
```

1x1px mail tracking image that will call above script

```
http://mysiteurl.com/location.php
```

Problem is when I am calling script directly then it is giving me real IP address of user which is in variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. But when script call from mail at that time its giving different IP address which is of Gmail SMTP or proxy IP of google.

My $_SERVER Details is:

```
{
   "PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin",
   "UNIQUE_ID":"Vl7beLia4QsAAHUl504AAAAF",
   "PHPHANDLER":"/usr/local/php53/bin/php",
   "HTTP_HOST":"saisoft.us",
   "HTTP_X_REAL_IP":"66.249.93.219",
   "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING":"gzip,deflate",
   "HTTP_CONNECTION":"close",
   "HTTP_USER_AGENT":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)",
   "SERVER_SOFTWARE":"Apache",
   "SERVER_NAME":"saisoft.us",
   "SERVER_ADDR":"181.224.138.204",
   "SERVER_PORT":"80",
   "REMOTE_ADDR":"66.249.93.219",
   "DOCUMENT_ROOT":"/home/saisoft9/public_html",
   "SERVER_ADMIN":"webmaster@saisoft.us",
   "SCRIPT_FILENAME":"/home/saisoft9/public_html/sugar/ss_custom/tracker_image.php",
   "REMOTE_PORT":"44678",
   "GATEWAY_INTERFACE":"CGI/1.1",
   "SERVER_PROTOCOL":"HTTP/1.0",
   "REQUEST_METHOD":"GET",
   "QUERY_STRING":"v_tracker_id=971295152638514267278685911477886786",
   "REQUEST_URI":"/sugar/ss_custom/tracker_image.php?v_tracker_id=971295152638514267278685911477886786",
   "SCRIPT_NAME":"/sugar/ss_custom/tracker_image.php",
   "PHP_SELF":"/sugar/ss_custom/tracker_image.php",
   "REQUEST_TIME":1449057144
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When your users open emails, Gmail uses Google’s secure proxy servers to serve images that might be included in these messages.

Gmail is using some **proxy** thing like `https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/SECURITY-TOKEN#http://mysiteurl.com/pixel`. In fact call to your server is coming from Gmail server, not directly from user's browser.

To solve this issue can you share result of `print_r($_SERVER);` ? I think there is `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` when proxy is in there.

There are more issues in there because of google proxy. Please have a look at this answer as well [images inside gmail email not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965219/images-inside-gmail-email-not-being-displayed)

Comment: I am always getting this IP '66.249.93.211'
I am not using any proxy. Also print_r($_SERVER);.. this gives me correct when I run script directly from browser
But by mail it is not giving correcr result

Comment: As per my understanding gmail is using some proxy thing like `gmail.com/outer_url.php?url=yourdomain.com/your_pixel_url.php?params`. So in fact call to your server is coming from gmain server, not directly from user's browser. Can you open your browser's developer console and see in network tab, what exacly url is fired for your pixel when you open an email?

Comment: yes sure 
https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/eqHE1UD-ojjncAnpFXPLGpx55tbMyRl3xjBWIIGQP5EXVCZBxMgvtCCPArqOFa696kONOgadOLFusn3G1NJbClh26EEvYFEDeQ1BZVnajLTuaDF8IYHrFZ8Jj_imsZWoMdQLMb7zGYMhX7GCoarSKC2w_pDWs3tQyvNY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://mysiteurl.com/location..php

Comment: Above URL is in my <img src=""> tag

Comment: wait let me explain
<img src="http://mysiteurl.com" />

This is I am attaching in mail content

Comment: - Open browser tab - Open gmail - Open developer's Console - Go to Network Tab - now open an test email having your pixel - And see what URL is being fired for pixel in console's network tab.

Comment: when I am opening mail then it is automatic adding 
https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/eqHE1UD-ojjncAnpFXPLGpx55tbMyRl3xjBWIIGQP5EXVCZBxMgvtCCPArqOFa696kONOgadOLFusn3G1NJbClh26EEvYFEDeQ1BZVnajLTuaDF8IYHrFZ8Jj_imsZWoMdQLMb7zGYMhX7GCoarSKC2w_pDWs3tQyvNY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://mysiteurl.com

Comment: I gave you URL that is firing

Comment: can you share result of `print_r($_SERVER);` ? I think there is `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`

Comment: ok let me share.. This is the json here of S_SERVER which I am getting from mail

Comment: {"PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin","UNIQUE_ID":"Vl7beLia4QsAAHUl504AAAAF","PHPHANDLER":"/usr/local/php53/bin/php","HTTP_HOST":"saisoft.us","HTTP_X_REAL_IP":"66.249.93.219",

Comment: "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING":"gzip,deflate","HTTP_CONNECTION":"close","HTTP_USER_AGENT":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","SERVER_SOFTWARE":"Apache","SERVER_NAME":"saisoft.us","SERVER_ADDR":"181.224.138.204","SERVER_PORT":"80","REMOTE_ADDR":"66.249.93.219","DOCUMENT_ROOT":"/home/saisoft9/public_html","SERVER_ADMIN":"webmaster@saisoft.us",

Comment: Better if you edit your question and add the answer there ?

Comment: Please check question again